# How can I book Greyhound online with a European address?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, buses, greyhound

I'd like to book a Greyhound bus ride from Chicago to New York. I don't live in the United States, so I don't have a US address. The American format asks for  address, zip code and telephone number for the online reservation ticket reservation and ticket. Is there a way I can do it with a European address, or is there any other option?

Comment: What format does it ask for when you choose the country you do live in? Maybe we're not looking at the same page, but when I pick "United Kingdom" as my country rather than "United States", the set of fields to enter my address changes to match the format for an address here in the UK. When I last booked a Greyhound ticket (a few years ago), I only had to enter my address for the card payment.

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary to pay money to make a Greyhound reservation.

As noted on Greyhound's [Payment and ticket options](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/ticket-info/payment-ticket-options) page, you can reserve online and then pay in person at a Greyhound station or at a partner retailer or agent.

On the passenger details page, simply choose *cash* under *Payment Details*, then fill in your contact details below. There is a field for ZIP code, but that is to let you look up nearby retailers, and not related to your actual contact information; you can just enter 60607 (the ZIP code of the [Chicago Greyhound terminal](http://locations.greyhound.com/bus-stations/us/illinois/chicago/bus-station-560252))

There is a checkbox that lets you indicate a non-[NANP](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/) phone number. You should then be able to proceed to make the reservation. Be sure to bring a printout of the reservation and identification when you arrive at the station.

Alternatively, you can try making the booking by phone, although the linked page suggests they may only be able to accept U.S. credit cards. The number is +1.800.231.2222 and you can choose either to pick up your ticket at the station or to have it emailed to you.

Comment: OP could also try to put in 90210 Beverly Hills as his address and see if the system accepts it. I'm 99% sure they don't care about the address.

Comment: @JonathanReez How could the system not accept that address?  If they didn't, how would locals from there take the bus?

Comment: @gerrit well OP is worried that his ticket would be invalid because he doesn't have an American address. I'm trying to say that he can input any valid address and it won't ever be checked by Greyhound or anyone else. Most people in America don't have proof of address on them when traveling, so it's probably just a useless field.

Comment: The address will probably be used for bank card verification purposes.

Comment: @AlP or for statistical purposes, in which case it might be more polite to try an invalid zip code such as 00000.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it is actually a bug in Greyhound's system, because I actually tried to leave it blank and submit a reservation and it wouldn't let me. It's supposed to be used to look up retailers where you can pay in person, but someone made it a mandatory field on a cash payment form, which doesn't make a lick of sense.

Comment: I'm not sure it's still possible to reserve online and pay cash, I'm no longer seeing that option work in the checkout on greyhound's website.

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud I literally just did it last night.

Comment: Odd, it's missing when I'm logged in to the site and greyed out when not for all dates are fares I've tried.

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud I wonder if they might block it from certain IPs (whether locale- or behavior-based criteria). There's no CAPTCHA, so I imagine they might get a lot of false registrations.

Answer (score 2):

You can also book through our site or apps over at [Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-company/greyhound), we're an authorized Greyhound ticket seller and have solved international data inputs and payment processing.

Comment: Thanks for disclosing your affiliation with Busbud! It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try. It's not a big deal. They ask your address as billing information so it's not very important and wont cause any problems as long as they get your money when you pay online. If they don't offer international address option without State/Zip Code. Just use State and Zip from where you plan to take the bus. I have some friends that used their hotel address.